# R remove suffix from variable names in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, wildcard, calculated-columns

I'm trying to remove suffix to variable names of a data frame in R to aggregate this columns.

I've imported a excel sheet into a data frame in R, but the column names where imported like this

```
var1...9   var2...10   var1...11   var2...12   var3.name...13
      12           7           5          10                6
       3           9          20           7               13
```

What I need is to remove the last part (from ...) to aggregate the columns by name.

```
var1   var2   var3.name
  17     17           6
  23     16          13
```

To do this I'm using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("...*")),
            .funs = funs(sub("[...]*$", "", .)))
```

but doesn't work, I think using * is not the appropriate way to use a wildcard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think using base R is easier here:

```
names(x) <- sub("\\.{3}\\d*$", "", names(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

With `rename_at`, we can use `matches` instead of `ends_with` as `ends_with` literally does a fixed match of the characters i.e. `.` and `*` instead of 3 dots followed by digits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>%
    rename_at(vars(matches('\\.{3}\\d+$')), ~ str_remove(., "\\.{3}\\d+$"))
```

NOTE: When we do this, it also returns a data.frame/tibble with duplicate column names (not recommended) based on the input example.

Comment: I agree it is not recommended to have duplicate column names, but my point is to sum by column name.

Comment: @Viskovitz if that was the case. you can just do `sapply(split.default(x, sub("\\.{3}.*", "", names(x))), rowSums)`